# Right-clicking (open in new tab) does not work for Inbox and Achievements

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

When I see a new message/achievement I would like to open it in a separate tab. This is particularly useful with slow connections. On right-clicking, the browser (Firefox) even announces the action "Open Link in New Tab", but the newly opened tab is just the very same page again. I expect to see what I otherwise get by simply following the link.

Edit: two motivations for this:

With slow connections, what you see is three animated dots and a tiny white window that partially hides the current page. By opening the page in another tab, I do not have to wait for the load to complete.

And then it's the common expectation. If I can click on a link, I can equally open it in another tab.

Comment: The inbox could link to your network wide profile, there's an *inbox* tab there (e.g. http://stackexchange.com/users/89883/stijn?tab=inbox). I haven't found a page with achievements though.

Comment: I ctrl+click to open in a new tab

Comment: I think you want a comma between `right-clicking` and `the browser`. I first read it as "On right-clicking Firefox, even announces..."

Comment: After clicking the icon, right-clicking items *in the lists* works fine for me, also in Firefox (on a Mac). Or are you talking about right-clicking the icons that shows the dropdown list? Would you expect that to open a new page with that dropdown expanded? (Also Cmd/Ctrl-click and Shift-click work as expected, for me.)

Comment: @Arjan: I meant right-clicking the original icon, where I do not want to wait until it loads. That's what I use right-click for.

Comment: As a regular click doesn't give you some new page with that information, I would not expect opening in a new window to work either. And I know you didn't tag it as bug but as a feature request, but the title reads like a bug to me. Maybe rephrase it to *"Add network-wide achievements overview (like the network wide Inbox)"* and also ask for opening the icons in a new tab/page to link to that? (The inbox icon then linking to the page Stijn referred to in the first comment.)

Comment: (@rene, this is about clicking the icons (not about clicking items *in the lists*). Cmd/Ctrl-click doesn't work for me for the icons either.)

Comment: I just did some experiment on those icons using Chrome's "Developer Tools" and it seems it's possible to set the link to user's "Response" and "Reputation" tab without breaking the pop-up menu. (I'm not an HTML expert at all, so I don't know if it's really possible from server side)

Comment: (Sorry for double-comment since 5 mins. has past) It should be possible, just like StackExchange pop-up menu beside Inbox icon.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: I'd like to see the content of this tiny window for Inbox or Achievement in a separate tab. If connections are slow, this takes time.

Comment: @Andrew, the linking is not a problem indeed. But *what* to link to for the network wide achievements? (Assuming Stijn's link for the global network wide Inbox would be fine for the Inbox icon.)

Comment: I still don't agree with your *"And then it's the common expectation. If I can click on a link, I can equally open it in another tab."* (And still suggest to make the title read as a feature request instead.)

Comment: Slightly related, about the "Inbox" text in *the popup* (not in the black header menu): [Inbox heading should be a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223737/inbox-heading-should-be-a-link).

Comment: @Arjan: We can probably agree that nobody expects that right-clicking on the icons gets one exactly the same page again. For, if anyone really would like to do that, clicking on one's gravatar already does that.

Comment: It is also problematic that this button doesn't work with JavaScript disabled (although this is actively a non-goal of StackExchange's interface …). If it were a normal link to `?tab=inbox`, this would be one less issue to deal with when JS is off.