# Inbox heading should be a link

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, top-bar, navigation

While looking at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223722/where-can-i-find-my-inbox), I noticed that the "INBOX" heading at the top of the new top bar inbox menu is not linked anywhere:

[image: Screenshot of Stack Exchange inbox menu, with "inbox" circled]

I'd like to suggest that, [like the similar headings in the site switcher menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218142/your-communities-in-site-switcher-menu-should-be-a-link), it *should* be a link.

Specifically, I'd like to suggest that it be linked to the network inbox page located at 
`http://stackexchange.com/users/<id>/<name>?tab=inbox`.

(It would also be nice if the similar heading on the achievements menu could also be a link, but I don't think there's any page summarizing the network-wide achievements of a user.  Maybe there should be?)

Comment: Since we already have it `see inbox items ` at the bottom.  I don't think it is needed.

Comment: If they're not going to style the headings properly to *look* like links, then I don't really see any point in making them links. I'd kind of rather see them move the "see inbox items" link to that bar, and float it to the right as a "see all" link or something (similar to the "edit" link next to Your Communities).

Comment: @animuson Gotcha! that is the perfect place to have to place the [link](http://stackexchange.com/users/<id>/<name>?tab=inbox) to inbox.

Comment: Related, to link *the icon* in the top bar, to allow for opening in a new window (right-click, Ctrl/Cmd-click, Shift-click): [Right-clicking (open in new tab) does not work for Inbox and Achievements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223590/right-clicking-open-in-new-tab-does-not-work-for-inbox-and-achievements?noredirect=1#comment728839_223590).

Comment: @Praveen Ugh. In 4+ years of Stack Overflow I have *never* noticed that link! Simply because you need to *scroll* all the way down to see it. I also had no idea there's an "inbox" tab on my Stack Exchange page, as I don't really look there very often. So yes, based on my personal experience, I would say this link would be *very* helpful.

Comment: Agree with @Carpet here, it will also be consistent with the SE dropdown to the left, where "Your Communities" and "More Stack Exchange Communities" are links, even though they are not styled as links

Comment: Should this be marked [status-completed], since the inbox icon itself now has a link to the inbox tab of your network profile?

Answer (score 2):

I kind of liked [animuson's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223737/inbox-heading-should-be-a-link#comment729291_223737) of putting the link on the right side of the heading, like the "edit" link in Your Communities, so I finally made it happen:

[image: Scheenshot]

The code that does this is included in the development branch of my [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script.  Assuming no unexpected issues show up, it should be part of the next stable SOUP release (v1.44).  If you're impatient, you also can install the development version via the link above.

The basic jQuery code to do this is actually pretty trivial:

```js
$('.topbar .inbox-dialog .inbox-se-link a').clone().insertAfter('.topbar .inbox-dialog h3:first-of-type').css('float', 'right')
```

This makes a copy of the "see all" link at the bottom of the inbox menu and adds it to the right of the menu header.  (Just to be safe and conservative, it leaves the original link where it is, too; removing the `.clone()` would make it just move the link instead of copying it.)

A slight complication is that the inbox menu is actually loaded via Ajax when clicked, so I need to monitor the Ajax requests and run the code after the menu has loaded.  Fortunately, SOUP already has a convenient utility method for that.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Apparently, [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223737/inbox-heading-should-be-a-link#comment729291_223737) has been implemented <sup>since when?</sup>.

> I'd kind of rather see them move the "see inbox items" link to that bar, and float it to the right as a "see all" link or something

"all items" link is added to the Inbox popup's header and links to `https://stackexchange.com/users/[user id]?tab=inbox`

[image: "all items" on inbox header!]